# Total of only positive (or negative) values in TimeSeries

Tags: summation, time-series

I've a `TimeSeries` like the following one:

```
fo = TimeSeries[{
   {{2020, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0},  -23},
   {{2020, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0},  -2},
   {{2020, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0}, 25},
   {{2020, 4, 30, 0, 0, 0}, 28}}
  ]
```

It's possible to calculate the sum of all values with `Total`

```
t = Total[fo]; (* t is -23 - 2 + 25 + 28 = 28 *)
```

The problem is that I'd like to find a way to calculate the sum only of positive (or zero) values, and otherwise the sum of only negative values, something like:

```
p = TotalPositive[fo]; (* p is 25 + 28 = 53 *)
n = TotalNegative[fo]; (* n is -2 - 23 = -25 *)
```

How can I sum only positive or negative values of this `TimeSeries`?

Comment: Try `pos[v_]:=If[Last[v]>0,Last[v],0];neg[v_]:=If[Last[v]<0,Last[v],0];` Then I did `Total[Map[pos, Normal[fo]]]` and `Total[Map[neg, Normal[fo]]]` where I seemed to need the `Normal` to get access to the values. Perhaps you can adapt this idea to your needs. There are certainly other ways of doing this. `Clip` might be one option.

Comment: `Total[Clip[fo, {0, Infinity}]]` and 
`Total[Clip[fo, {-Infinity, 0}]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions.